# How to keep all leading spaces in a text field (Drupal)

Tags: entities, wysiwyg

I need to allow users to insert leading spaces in their text. It appears that the default text field chopps off all leading spaces.
I tried ckeditor and BUEeditor but they appear also to remove leading spaces, and I don't see any way to prevent that.

If possible, I don't want to use any text editor if possible.

Thanks

Comment: That's how HTML works, and what the `&nbsp;` character exists for. Trying to hold on to leading spaces is almost definitely the sign of an incorrect approach; styling should be done with CSS, not characters

Comment: The users need to indent the text they insert the way they want, using spaces.

Comment: I understood the question, I was just saying that it's not a Drupal/Ckeditor/BUeditor/AnythingElseEditor issue.  The display of multiple concurrent spaces is handled by HTML & CSS specs, as you've already discovered yourself from the looks of your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution I found using the class
white-space: pre;